# R build TermDocumentMatrix with removeSparseTerms parameter

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, term-document-matrix

Am I able to remove sparse terms WHILE creating a `tm::TermDocumentMatrix` object?

I tried:

```
TermDocumentMatrix(file.corp, control = list(removeSparseTerms=0.998))
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Please add reproducible data set. This is expected when you ask a question. We don't have `file.corp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot remove sparse terms like that with the `TermDocumentMatrix` function. If you check the help for that function with `?TermDocumentMatrix` you'll see that the options for `control` are listed in the help for  `termFreq`, and when you look at the help for that function with `?termFreq`, you'll see that `removeSparseTerms` is not listed there. Although you have `bounds` which can do a related job.

If you just want a one-liner that combines `TermDocumentMatrix` and `removeSparseTerms`, you simply flip your line inside-out and that will work fine:

```
removeSparseTerms(TermDocumentMatrix(file.corp), 0.998)
```

I recommend you have a careful look at the documentation for the `tm` package, it's one of better examples of a well-documented contributed package. It might save you time waiting for someone to answer your questions here!

Comment: Thank you for your attention, Ben! You are right, I should put more interest on the package's documentation.